# What is the best cloud system to display company data in data visualizations?

Tags: database, architecture, operating-system, cloud, system

I know ToughtSpot and Snowflake can do this. The piece im looking for is displaying visualizations and show the Top 10 worst offenders. A second party (the vendor) can login and use a drop-down to assign a reason to the worst offenders. This reason would feed back into our companies database to be used in internal reporting. What system can support this functionality?

ThoughtSpot and Snowflake